# In Table View , label is getting overlapped by other text when scrolled through tableview .

Tags: ios, label, tableview

[image: After Scrolling labels are overlapped]

[image: Before scrolling through tableview]

I have added custom label to the tableview . But When i scroll it looks like the given picture .

I am adding the code too . `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailPlacePage"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.placeTableViewController indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NomadPlaceDetailViewController *placedetailcontroller = segue.destinationViewController;
    placedetailcontroller.myDictionary = [self.placeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

}
`

Comment: Issue is with your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. When you reuse a cell remove old content(Label) from the cell and add new content(label).

Comment: I am new to development , please guide me through code which i can implement directly

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944604/objective-c-uitableview-cells-get-written-over-each-time-when-scrolling-up-and

Comment: Thanks alot @NitinGohel , Can you help me with other bugs i am getting ?

Comment: like which type of bugs i m not getting you and you have to first find the solution with some Google RND and relevant issue and its solution instead of directly asking question.

Comment: I have searched alot on google and stachoverflow dude , this the problem is not solved . i have even posted the question here ,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789023/segue-is-blank-black-cant-view-the-data?noredirect=1#comment29439733_19789023

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your cell identifier try this code. Hope this may help you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;

   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {        
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
   return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: then it is best practice to reuse it's subviews also if you are adding additional subviews in cell.

You can write your cellForRowAtIndexPath like following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UITextField *myView;

    if (cell == nil)
    {        
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        myView = [[UITextField alloc] init];  // Set frame as required
        myView.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myView];
    }

    myView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    myView.text = @"YourText";
   return cell;

}
```

What happens here is it adds `myView` only once when cell is `nil`, and after that it will reuse previously added `myView` to set Text so `myView` will not be added multiple times and that solves problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you initialize and adding the labels outside of `if(cell == nil)` condition. So every time you scroll the table view, the code for adding labels executed and new labels creating. So just place them inside of your `if(cell == nil)` condition. Only data displaying section should place outside `if(cell == nil)`.

Comment: Cell will never be nil if using prototype cells and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier